# Version code updating

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app on play store with different versions...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kishansinh.global

How do I know my app is updating while user update his/her app from the play store?

like user use **versionCode=1** app and i publish app with **versionCode=2**  so user update app easily but i want to handle somethink when app is updating from the play store and some think to change in app...

i little searching and got the somethink to use **PACKAGE_UPDATING** , **PACKAGE_INSTALL**

```
<receiver name="com.etc.etc.listenerClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and second method is that i change Database Version Code and handle from the **onUpgrade** Method

but what is the real technique to handle listener for app updating?